# I couldn't pass the value to any variables though i used body-parser. When i try to print "username" it's value is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I tried to create a form for my login page. Even when I enter the fields with the correct data, I get email does not exist. So i tried printing the variable "username" and found out that value is not being passed. The result is "undefined".

Server.JS

I have used body-parser to pass value to my variable username in login.js

```
var express    = require("express");
var login = require('./routes/loginroutes');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
var router = express.Router();
// test route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.json({ message: 'welcome to our upload module apis' });
});
//route to handle user registration

router.post('/login',login.login)
app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(5000);
```

Login.js

Since my variable username is not showing any value, I tried printing it in log. The result says "undefined".

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'mynodedb',
port:3307
});
connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
console.log("Database is connected ... nn");
} else {
console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");
}
});




exports.login = function(req,res){
var username= req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username], 
function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) {
// console.log("error ocurred",error);
res.send({
"code":400,
"failed":"error ocurred"
})
}else{
// console.log('The solution is: ', results);
console.log(username);
if(results.length >0){
if([0].password == password){
res.send({
      "code":200,
      "success":"login sucessfull"
        });
  }
  else{
    res.send({
      "code":204,
      "success":"Email and password does not match"
        });
  }
}
else{
  res.send({
    "code":204,
    "success":"Email does not exits"
      });
}
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Content-type you are sending is application/json.
And make sure you are sending both fields in the body: username / password

Comment: can you check what is coming in `req`

Comment: how do i do that @yogeshagrawal